# Dynamic arrays (represented with pointers) in C++ - entering elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, element

I have a homework task where I should create an array and implement the bubble sort algorithm with pointers only. I create the array, but if I want to input `3` elements, i.e if the user enters n = 3, the program does not allow me entering the third number. I want to ask why this happens?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *n = new int ;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Vavedete broya na chislata:"<<' ';
    cin>>*n;
    int *arr = new int[*n];
    cout<<"Vavedete elementite:"<<endl;
    int *i=new int;
    for(*i=0; *i<*n; *i++)
    {
        cin>>*(arr+*i);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: want to draw your attention to the fact that the accepted answer is wrong about the same precedence of `*` and `++`. That is true only if `++` is prefix operator. In your case we have postfix which has higher precision. Of course, in this specific example that doesn't matter.

Comment: Also there is a good reason to use prefix instead of postfix than you can, i will update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both '*' and '++' operators have the same precedence but the associativity is right to left.You are dereferencing  i++ which is not used in the loop.
try:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int *n = new int ;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Vavedete broya na chislata:"<<' ';
    cin>>*n;
    int *arr = new int[*n];
    cout<<"Vavedete elementite:"<<endl;
    int *i=new int;
    for(*i=0; *i<*n; (*i)++)
    {
        cin>>*(arr+*i);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Precedence of postfix increment is higher than of indirection operator, so in the loop you need to write `++*i`, with your current implementation on the second iteration `*i` contains a garbage, thus you write into not intended location. You can check the precedence table [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Also, there is a good reason to use prefix increment, because when you will start to use iterators by this you will avoid creation of temporary object.

Answer (score 0):

in your for loop u should put brackets (*i)++ because when u wrote *i++ first u increase address of i then get it's value

```
 for (*i = 0; *i<*n; (*i)++)
    {
        cin >> *(arr + *i);

    }
```